# How to find an angle to rotate vector to align with a point

Tags: geometry

[image: Problem illustration]

We know the value of point $T$ is $(x, y)$.

From $(0, 0)$ there is a line to point $p$ (I'll call this line $D$) with length $d$ and at that point, there is a vector (I'll call it $V$) that has an angle $\theta$ with $D$.

The problem is how to find an angle $\theta'$ that makes $V$ align with $T$?

I've tried to calculate $\theta'$ by

1. Calculate $l = \text{distance from T to (0, 0)}$
2. Find $r$ by using law of cosine $r = d\cos{\theta} \pm \sqrt{l^2 - d^2\sin{\theta}}$
3. Using $r$ to create a circle from point $T$ with radius $r$ and find an intersection point $p'$ with circle from $(0, 0)$ with radius $d$
4. Calculate the distance between $p'$ and $p$ and use it as a base of a triangle that has point $p$, $p'$ and $(0, 0)$ as a vertex
5. We can calculate $\theta' = 2\arctan{\frac{0.5 \times \text{triangle_base}}{d}}$

[image: Illustration of above method]

Is there a simpler way to solve this problem?

Comment: One can find angle between $l$ and $d$ before and after rotation. Then rotation angle is difference of those. One can also make calculations in complex numbers. Let $T=x+iy$, $P=a+ib$, $V=c+id$, then $T-Pe^{i\phi}=kVe^{i\phi}$ with some real $k$. $k$ can be calculated from $|T|=|P+kV|$, then $e^{i\phi}=\frac{T}{P+kV}$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the line before rotation is

$ r(t) = D + t V $

In terms of coordinates, this is

$ r(t)= (D_1, D_2) + t (V_1, V_2) $

This is the vector equation of the line.  Define the perpendicular to the line by

$N = (-V_2, V_1) $

then it follows that the algebraic equation of the line is

$ N \cdot ( r - D ) = 0 $

After rotation by an angle $\theta'$ counterclockwise, the image of a point $r$ is $r'$ given by

$ r'(t) = R(\theta') r $

where

$R(\theta') = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta') && -\sin(\theta') \\ \sin(\theta') && \cos(\theta') \end{bmatrix} $

From this, it follows that

$ r = R^{-1}(\theta') r' = R^T (\theta') r' $

Hence, the equation of the rotated line is

$ N \cdot ( R^T r' - D ) = 0 $

Now we want point $ Q  $ (I've changed it from $T$ to $Q = [Q_1, Q_2]$) to lie on this rotated line.  Substitute $r' = A$

$ N \cdot ( R^T Q - D ) = 0 $

Everything here is known except $\theta'$.  Expanding the above equation,

$ [-V_2, V_1]\cdot (  [ Q_1 \cos(\theta') + Q_2 \sin(\theta') , - Q_1 \sin(\theta') + Q_2 \cos(\theta') ]^T - [D_1, D_2] ) = 0 $

Collecting terms, this is of the form

$ A \cos(\theta') + B \sin(\theta') = C $

where

$ A = -  V_2 Q_1 +  V_1 Q_2 $

$ B = - V_2 Q_2 - V_1 Q_1 $

$ C = -V_2 D_1 + V_1 D_2 $

And this equation has two solutions

$ \theta' = \phi \pm \cos^{-1} \left( \dfrac{ C }{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}\right) $

where $ \phi $ is the angle such that $ \cos(\phi) =\dfrac{ A }{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}$,  $\hspace{4pt}\sin(\phi) = \dfrac{ B}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}} $